# About the definition of textcolor

Tags: color, arguments, texdef

I was curious and found the following definition for the macro `textcolor` defined in the package `xcolor`:

```latex
\def\textcolor#1#{\@textcolor{#1}}
\def\@textcolor#1#2#3{\protect\leavevmode{\color#1{#2}#3}}
```

However, I use the macro with only two arguments and not three arguments:

```latex
\textcolor{blue}{foo}
```

What I don't understand for this definition is:

1. What is the meaning of the syntax `\textcolor#1#`?
2. What will be the third argument the macro `\@textcolor` will get in the example above?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is primitive tex syntax that really shouldn't be used in a latex package. It's used here as in 1993 fitting this all into a 640K machine we were *really* short of space and saving a few dozen bytes by shortcutting the definition was worth it.

If you go

```
\def\foo#1#{zzz #1 zzz}
```

then `#1` is everything from `\foo` to the first brace, so

```
\foo one two three {zzz}
```

then `#1` would be `one two three`

Using this allows `\textcolor` to grab any optional arguments without actually parsing for them and then re-insert them so `\color` sees them.

so compare

```
\textcolor{blue}{foo}
```

and

```
\textcolor[rgb]{0,0,1}{foo}
```

in the first case `#1` is empty so the expansion is

```
  \@textcolor{}{blue}{foo}
```

which is

```
  \protect\leavevmode{\color{blue}foo}
```

but in the second case `#1` is `[rgb]` (including the brackets) so the first expansion is

```
\@textcolor{[rgb]}{0,0,1}{foo}
```

which is

```
 \protect\leavevmode{\color[rgb]{0,0,1}foo}
```

so the `[rgb]` isn't really ever seen by `\textcolor` as an optional argument, it is just grabbed and passed to `\color`.

Comment: Thank you for your clear answer. Is the second sharp after `#1` really necessary then?

Comment: @Saroupille Yes, otherwise it would only read the first token after `\textcolor` which would be `[` in the case of an optional argument.